# При переносе битов получаеться минусовое число [C++]

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Пишу код он правильно работает,но число получаеться минусовое,почему?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int d = 0;
  *((char*)&d + 3) = 1;// 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000‬
  d = d << 7; //переношу биты на 7 позиций влево
  cout << d;// выводит нужное число,но минусовое почему?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте про бит отвечающий за знак в знаковом представлении

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `int d = 0` написать `unsigned int d = 0`, этого вы хотели?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если предположить, что ваш изначальный трюк с

```
*((char*)&d + 3) = 1;
```

породил ожидаемое вами начальное значение переменной `d` (`16777216`)‬, то значение выражения

```
d << 7;
```

равно `‭2147483648‬` и, по-видимому, не помещается в диапазон типа `int` на вашей платформе. Это означает, что поведение выражения `d << 7` не определено.

Так что никакого "минусового числа" у вас не получается. У вас получается *неопределенное поведение*.

---

Новая спецификация операторов сдвига, готовящаяся для С++2x (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift), существенно деформализует поведение этих операторов и приближает их к реальной практике. Однако я навскидку не понимаю, собираются ли стандартизаторы "отменить" переполнение во время знакового сдвига влево.